# Is it possible to load controller from subfolders in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

I need to load `controllers/site/user/UserController.php` controller from `Route.php` file.

P.S. I don't need to add  automatically it to auto load class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First, you need to namespace the controller, like:

```
<?php namespace Site\User;
```

Now, from your routes, you call the methods in `UserController` by prefixing the namespace of the class like:

```
Route::get('users', 'Site\User\UserController@index');
```

Comment: still no luck... My structure looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/searp89ep05h6yj/snapshot79.png, no auto-loading included...

Comment: I am using a similar structure, and it works. When you're working in subfolders, you'll need to specify that the classes that you want to use are in global namespace. For example: `\BaseController` instead of `BaseController`. If you show the error that you're getting, then we'd get more insight to your problem.